# bind textboxes created in js to an item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

My objective to have polymophism in ng-repeat. Each field has different html (generated by jquery).

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-bind-html="field.html"></div>
```

For example, $scope.fields[0].html is

```
<input ng-model="field.bio">
```

$scope.fields[1].html is

```
<label>what's your name?</label><input ng-model="field.name">
```

I hope that when the textboxes have input, the bio or name attribute the corresponding field would be populated. However, it's not.

So I want to know how to bind those textboxes created in js to an item in ng-repeat?

Comment: Do you know each field ahead of time, or are they completely dynamic?

Comment: It's tough to say without knowing a data structure, maybe think about organizing the structure if you have control over that. There would ideally be a model controlling it somewhere that would shape it into an easily workable format for your front end.

Comment: I figured out another way to achieve polymorphism - first create a directive to replace to <div>, then in the directive template, use ng-if to branch into different html

Comment: That's not true polymorphism if you are setting an ng-if for each scenario. but if it works, great!